# My conditional rows are coming over as a string of all data in one cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is what I have:

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
.getSheetByName('Base').getRange('A:M').getValues();
 var row, len, data = [];

for (row = 0, len = values.length; row < len; row++)
if (values[row][12] == 'Red') 
  data.push([values[row]]);

var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
.getSheetByName('Basics');
dest.clearContents();
var lastRow = dest.getLastRow();
dest.getRange('A1:M1').offset(lastRow, 0, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

It is working, in that it is getting all the data from the source sheet correctly, but in my dest, it is just putting all the data from all cells into cell A1, rather than corresponding cells.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It copies without any empty rows in the destination sheet.

```
function copyValues(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Base');
var values = sheet.getRange('A:M').getValues();
 var row, data = [];
  for (row = 0, len = sheet.getLastRow(); row < sheet.getLastRow(); row++){
if (values[row][12] == 'Red') 
  data.push(values[row]);
  }

var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Basics');
dest.clearContents();
dest.getRange(1, 1, data.length, 13 ).setValues(data);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: 13 could be replaced by a more universal data[0].length

Answer (score 1):

Could you do it this way (tested) instead? I'm not sure offset() works the way you're intending it to work.

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var origSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Base');
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Basics');

  var values = origSheet.getRange('A:M').getValues();
  destSheet.clearContents();

  var row, len, data = [];

  for (row = 0, len = values.length ; row < len ; row++){
    if (values[row][12] == 'Red')
      data.push(values[row]);
  }

  if(data.length > 0)
    destSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here's some new code that will copy over values AND formulae. Perhaps it's not the most elegant solution, but it works and it should be relatively efficient.

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var origSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Base');
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Basics');

  var values = origSheet.getRange('A:M').getValues();
  var formulas = origSheet.getRange('A:M').getFormulas();
  destSheet.clearContents();

  var data = [];

  for(var row = 0 ; row < values.length ; row++){
    if (values[row][12] == 'Red'){
      for(var col = 0 ; col < formulas[row].length ; col++){
        if(formulas[row][col] != ''){
          values[row][col] = formulas[row][col];
        }
      }
      data.push(values[row]);
    } 
  }

  if(data.length > 0)
    destSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: (thx for editing your answer) - 13 could be replaced by a more universal data[0].length

Comment: ok, so, this may need to be a separate question, but maybe it is quick... one part of my range has hyperlinks.  Any way to gather the hyperlink with this rather than just the displayed text?  I tried .getFormulas()

Comment: I just tried it out with links and they're all transferring to the second sheet... Are your hyperlinks, perhaps, in a column beyond column M?

Comment: Nope.. in the first column.  Strange, the display text is showing only.  Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Just tried it again with all the links in the first column... still works. Maybe make a shared spreadsheet with some test data for us to try?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eIDq9lvPXYcoE8we0jTKHk0L3oOFcu5arE7DOazj390/edit#gid=0

Comment: I see now. For my tests, I was using simple links, like "www.google.com", that weren't a part of a =HYPERLINK() formula. I added some new code above that copies over values and formulae.

Comment: No problem! Please mark the question as "answered" if you feel that  it's appropriate. Thanks!